# Agent roll going super far?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

so i've seen agents (operatives and snipers) do super far rolls sometimes in PvP and i'm wondering how this works?
Usually its when they start the fight, they will do a roll, and as the ground under their feet dissapears, they roll super far in one go.

I've only have this happen once or twice myself, and i'm not sure whats causing it.
Is it a certain distance you need to be in the air? or roll and jump or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't start a roll roll while in the air, but you will go farther if you roll off a ledge.  That's all there is to it.  Note that Operatives/Scoundrels can roll twice for 24 meters total, whereas Snipers/Gunslingers can only roll once for 18 meters.

There's also a trick called a "rollbang" where you do actually press jump as you trigger the roll in order to roll much shorter, not farther!

Comment: Perhaps i there have been situations where i see a sniper roll for 18m in one go off a ledge and consider it to be the same roll as my operative; thx!

Comment: Note that sometimes if you roll off a ledge it looks like it's going much furter then it's actually is.